# How to send mails by attaching a file (file should be taken from Sql Server Database)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I Created a Table

```
create table files
(
id int identity(1,1),
Name_of_file varchar(50) null,
interviewfile varbinary(max) Null,
)
```

**Inserting .doc file in to Files Table**

```
insert into files 
select 'DB Creation' as filetype, *
from openrowset
(BULK 'E:\Office Works\Get SMS\DBA SMS Exam Stuff with 
DocumentationStandards\Interview Questions\Indexes-I.doc', SINGLE_BLOB)
as x
```

now i want to send the "Indexes-I.doc" file as an attachment to Particular Mail ID.

How should i Attach and How to send it using Asp.Net 3.5

Please tell me the Solution..........

Thanks & Regards,
Venkat Kumar Chigulla.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the bellow link
                                                                                          http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rahul4_saxena/send-email-in-Asp-Net-with-attached-file/
and 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10828/Sending-Email-with-attachment-in-ASP-NET-using-SMT

might help you..

Answer (score 0):

You might need little modification but this will do.

```
private void SendEmail(string toAddress, string ccAddress, string bccAddress, string subject, string body, MailPriority priority, bool isHtml)
    {
        try
        {
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

            MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("sample@hotmail.com");

            smtpClient.Host = "xxx.xxx.com";
            smtpClient.Port = 25;

            message.From = fromAddress;
            message.Priority = priority;
            message.To.Add(toAddress);
            message.Subject = subject;
            if (ccAddress.Length > 0)
            {
                message.CC.Add(ccAddress);
            }
            if (bccAddress.Length > 0)
            {
                message.Bcc.Add(bccAddress);
            }

            message.IsBodyHtml = isHtml;
            message.Body = body;

            //load attachment from database
            sConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["eCIConnectionString"].ToString();
            try
            {
                sSQL = @"SELECT id, Name_of_file,  interviewfile" +
                        @"FROM files " +
                        @"WHERE Name_of_file = 'Your FileName'";

                conn.ConnectionString = sConn;
                conn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = sSQL;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();

                dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dAdapter.Fill(dt);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        byte[] barrImg = (byte[])dt.Rows[i]["interviewfile"];
                        string strfn = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Name_of_file"]);
                        FileStream fs = new FileStream(strfn, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
                        fs.Write(barrImg, 0, barrImg.Length);

                        fs.Flush();
                        fs.Close();
                        fs.Dispose();

                        Attachment att = new Attachment(strfn);
                        message.Attachments.Add(att);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string error = ex.Message + ex.StackTrace;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn != null)
                {
                    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                    conn.Dispose();
                }
                if (cmd != null)
                {
                    cmd.Dispose();
                }
            }

            // Send SMTP mail
            smtpClient.Send(message);

            lblMessage.Text = "Email sent to " + toAddress + " successfully !";
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = ee.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: I'm facing a problem to call the Function in my "btnsend_click" event protected void btnsend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e )            {                                                          SendEmail();                                                        }

Comment: Error: No overload for Method 'SendEmail' takes '0' arguments.

Comment: so i added this code "SendEmail(string toAddress, string ccAddress, string bccAddress, string subject, string body, MailPriority priority, bool isHtml);"  in my btnsend_click() event to call that function

Comment: Just remove the parameters from the function definition and set the values for string toAddress, string ccAddress, string bccAddress, string subject, string body, MailPriority priority, bool isHtml locally inside the method.

Comment: now it's working but this time i got runtime Error **System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out. at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at _Default.SendEmail() in e:\Web Application Projects\attachfilesfromdb\Default.aspx.cs:line 131**

Comment: **if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)** the above code doesn't run it's directly went to **Catch block**

Comment: Why??? You have one file retrieved from your db i.e dt.Rows.Count=1 and so it will enter that condition. try putting Port = 465 instead

Comment: It enters the loop and execute till this line **FileStream fs = new FileStream(strfn, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);**  and directly move to **Catch() block**. and got the same error System.Net.Mail as above

Comment: That means you are getting different error, right? It's really tough for me to point out the exact error now as I am unable to debug. Please catch the exact error, may be the stacktrace and post it. The error what you are getting is the higher level exception not the exact one.

Comment: Put a try/catch block inside that for loop and track the exact error.